# Expressions of gratitude

Tags: translation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCORe7qs0Sk
at 3:13 the man on the left saying something to show gratitude.
it's not arigatou gozaimasu or domo arigatou, or something like that.
it's sounds like "koteii ni domo" I can't find it in any dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

ご丁寧にどうも
(Go-teinei ni doumo)

Thank you. That's very thoughtful of you.

Comment: I thought 丁寧 meant polite? Why isn't it "thank you for being polite"?

Comment: It can mean polite, but also something done with thoughtfulness/consideration to detail (e.g. 丁寧にアイロンをかける).

Comment: Politeness and thoughtfulness are not mutually exclusive; and being polite may include being considerate to details. The definition from Meikyou helps me understand how these two concepts are related: (a) 隅ずみまで注意が行き届き、落度の無いことを期待する様子。(b) 相手の△立場（気持）を考えて、真心のこもった応対をする様子。